# Magento Category Custom Design changes does not work from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout-update, magento-1.9.3.4

I have to change design change only for one category. I have changed the design from admin panel for a particular category, but it does not update in the frontend.

Does anybody have the same problem?

there are so many modules, all are useful.
Does this can effected by any module?

Comment: Describe what code you have try from admin for category changes?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Have not modify any code level changes.

Comment: I am asking the changes, which you try from admin and not affected into frontend. Are you getting my point.

Comment: only for test 1name cateogry , want modern theme for others want rwd.  These what i change from admin. For test 1 category , change theme from category setting modern , also tried same from store level and website level. Also Set "No" on Use parent category setting.